# Trying to create a function to calculate over 6 months instead of a year

Tags: r, function, filter

I have created a function in r which does some calculation by filtering each Year. Now I want to filter out 6months from each year. For eg 2014 will be divided into two dataframes 20140101-201406 and 20140701-20141201.

I tried using logical operators in the filter command and it keeps giving me errors as an unexpected symbol.

```r
func2 <- function(years, data) {
years <- c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019)
listofdfs <- list()
efor(i in 1:length(years)) {
#d <- data[data$Year == years[i]]
d <- filter(data, (data$Year==years[i]))
df <- data.frame(d)[, c(4,5)]
names(df) <- unlist(d[1, "headers"])
names(df)[1:2] <- c("Actual", "Estimated")
listofdfs[[i]] <- df
  }
return(listofdfs)
}
```

expected should give me dataframes with 6rows for each month but it gives out the whole year instead

Edit:

This is what I tired:

```r
func2 <- function(years, data) { 

  years <- c(20140101, 20140601, 20140701,20141201, 20150101, 20150601, 20150701, 20151201, 20160101,20191201)

  listofdfs <- list() for(i in 1:length(years)) { #d <- data[data$Year == years[i]] 

  d <- filter(data, (years[i]==data$Year || years[i]<data$Year) | data$Year==inc(years)[i] || data$Year<inc(years[i]))

  df <- data.frame(d)[, c(4,5)] 

  names(df) <- unlist(d[1, "headers"]) 
}
```

[This is what the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exS9p.png)

Comment: func2 <- function(years, data) {
  years <- c(20140101, 20140601, 20140701,20141201, 20150101, 20150601, 20150701, 20151201, 20160101... 20191201)
  listofdfs <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(years)) {
    #d <- data[data$Year == years[i]]
    d <- filter(data, (years[i]==data$Year || years[i]<data$Year) | data$Year==inc(years[i] || data$Year<inc(years[i]))
    df <- data.frame(d)[, c(4,5)]
    names(df) <- unlist(d[1, "headers"])
   This is what I tried

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data, 20))`. Also, what is `inc(years[i])`? Function `inc()` is not defined in the code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split the data into semesters, here is a base R approach with no loops at all.

```
fun <- function(data){
  d <- as.Date(data[[1]], format = "%Y%m%d")
  m <- as.integer(format(d, "%m"))
  semester <- 2 - (m <= 6)
  year <- format(d, "%Y")
  split(data, list(semester, year))
}
```

Just pass the data set to this function, it outputs a list of dataframes, one per semester/year.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code!

In line 2 there is a closing bracket ) missing after "2019". This alone could account for your error.

But without sample data it is hard to solve your original problem.

Edit 1:

It is really hard to say what your problem is because the code you have added in the post and the comment has too many syntax errors to pinpoint the problem.

Maybe those syntax mistakes are the problem but there are too many, there are a lot of closing brackets missing, commented out lines, etc.

If I take your code example this is what it would look like just taking out those mistakes, does that solve your problem?

```r
func2 <- function(years, data) { 

  years <- c(20140101, 20140601, 20140701,20141201, 20150101, 20150601, 20150701, 20151201, 20160101,20191201)

  listofdfs <- list() for(i in 1:length(years)) {

  #d <- data[data$Year == years[i]] 

  d <- filter(data, (years[i]==data$Year || years[i]<data$Year) | data$Year==inc(years)[i] || data$Year<inc(years[i]))

  df <- data.frame(d)[, c(4,5)] 

  names(df) <- unlist(d[1, "headers"])
  }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

So here is a solution:

```r
# Sample data that looks like yours

years <- c(20140101, 20140601, 20140701,20141201, 20150101, 20150601, 20150701, 20151201, 20160101)
test <- c("A", "A","A","B","B","B", "C", "C", "C")

df <- data.frame(years,test)

library(dplyr)

# This code creates a splitting variable, Halfyear
df %>%
  separate(years,into = c("Year","Month","Day"), sep = c(4,6)) %>%
  mutate(Halfyear = paste(Year,case_when(Month <= 6 ~ "First Half",TRUE ~ "Second Half"))) %>%
  mutate(Halfyear = as.factor(Halfyear)) %>%
  {.} -> df

# Now we can use split to create the relevant data frames and access them with [i] where i is the index of the half year
  as.data.frame(split(df,f = df$Halfyear)[1]) %>%
  head()
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hey, I made some errors in the syntax while posting the question. I think it should be fine now.Edit 1: just has the code that I tried. I also posted a picture of how the dataframe looks like if that helps?

Comment: @RohanJain And the end result should be two data frames per year, each containing one row per month? I'll think I have a solution, I edit in a minute.

Comment: Do you want me to add it in the function?

Comment: @RohanJain no this replaces the whole function but you could build a new function out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `split` or `by` to subset dataframe into a list of data frames by one or more factors, specifically *year* and calculated *year_half*:

```
df$year_half <- ifelse(as.integer(substring(df$Year, 5, 6)) <= 6, 
                       "first_half", "second_half")

# SIMILAR CALLS:
listofdfs <- split(df, list(df$year, df$year_half))
listofdfs <- by(df, df[,c("year", "year_half")], FUN=identity)
```

Comment: do you want me to include it in the function? 
func2 <- function(years, data) {
years <- c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019)
listofdfs <- list()
efor(i in 1:length(years)) {
#d <- data[data$Year == years[i]]
d <- filter(data, (data$Year==years[i]))
df <- data.frame(d)[, c(4,5)]
names(df) <- unlist(d[1, "headers"])
names(df)[1:2] <- c("Actual", "Estimated")
listofdfs[[i]] <- df
  }
return(listofdfs)
}

Comment: Did you run this solution? `split` and `by` will subset across ALL *years* and *year_half* in data. You do not need to supply anything or initialize any empty list. Please advise how either of the two solutions above does not help you.

Comment: this gives me the column year_half but its filled with NAs

Comment: Try converting to character first: `...substring(as.character(df$Year), 5, 6)...`